# CRUD approach practice

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Following many tutorials from official and non-official docs, there is no such a clear vision for common approach for creating editing the entity and updating just specific fields.

The main questions are:
1 - Create the entity - fill the form, validate, create entity object and populate it with exchangeArray and then save, in save method via docs we must configure an array from passed object like:

```
$data = array(
            'artist' => $album->artist,
            'title'  => $album->title,
        );
```

Can we avoid this array re-configuring in save method?

2 - Update the entity - same logic

3 - What if we want to update only one specific field?
I pass the array to updateEntity method, but is it normal way to pass object(and configure array inside method) to save method and pass array to update method?

4 - Almost same thing with 3 but issue now when we have an array with another keys among our entity fields keys, we can strip 'bad' array keys using hydrator and make something like array_intersect style, but what you suggest?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is - what is the best practice of implementing crud system in ZF2 taking into account mentioned cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smart combination of your entity, form, input filter and hydrator to have almost no logic to get CRUD things done. For an admin interface I usually generate my controller, form and other classes. I use Sublime Text 2 and the snippets to generate these classes can be found in my [repository](https://github.com/juriansluiman/sublime-zf2-snippets).

This results in:

1. A controller with index (listing), view (single item), create, update and delete
2. A form to contain all entity fields
3. A repository (Doctrine) to query entities
4. A service to persist to the database (either create one, save one or delete one)

This will solve #1 and #2. Due to the way ZF2 filtering and hydration works, this will also solve #4 for you. Then, it is possible to set only a select no. of fields to be filtered, but I have not implemented that (yet). I can only refer to [the manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups) to know how to do that.

If you want to know the implementation of above snippets, take a look at [Soflomo\Portfolio](https://github.com/Soflomo/Portfolio) which uses a similar strategy.

Answer (score -3):

PHP, contrary to other languages, is array centric than object centric.  Most task could be done via Array. In this case, instead of use

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public $artist;
    public $title;
}
$album=new SomeClass();
$data = array(
        'artist' => $album->artist,
        'title'  => $album->title,
    );
?>
```

We should use

```
<?
$SomeObject=array("artist"=>xxx,"title"=>xxxx);

$data = $someObject;
?>
```

i.e. we should avoid to use classes when we are referencing a POCO class and instead we should use the (less elegant) array.  Otherwise, sometimes we will be forced to do such conversion between array and object.

Anyways i we will need to keep it as a object then, we can do the conversion between object to array using:

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public $artist;
    public $title;
}
$album=new SomeClass();
$data = (array)$album;
?>
```

However, this conversion sometimes is tricky.